# Subtract Time and Date in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have these values in Excel cells

```
A1 =  Aug 14 2013 11:40AM
B1 =  Aug 16 2013 5:39PM
```

I need to subtract `A1` from `B1`, and I need the answer in `C1` in `hh,mm,ss` format.

I am trying this

`INT('Original Data'!B1-'Original Data'!A1)*24 + TEXT(MOD('Original Data'!B1-'Original Data'!A1,1)*24,"0.00")& " Hours")`

Can anybody help me with this Problem?

Comment: Is that data stored as text or as date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the values in **A1** and **B1** are *true* Excel DateTImes then the formula:

```
=B1-A1
```

will display:  2.249305556
if the format is General

Change the format to:

**[hh],mm,ss**

and you should see:

**53,59,00**